# npm can't find in my cmd after I install using nvm

Tags: nvm

I install npm using nvm by doing 'nvm install 6.11.2'. It said the installation is successful. But when I execute 'npm' in my prompt. It said command not found.

Where does nvm install npm? so that i can update the path for cmd.

```
C:\Users\john>nvm install 6.11.2
Downloading node.js version 6.11.2 (64-bit)...
Complete
Creating C:\Users\john\AppData\Roaming\nvm\temp

Downloading npm version 3.10.10... Complete
Installing npm v3.10.10...

Installation complete. If you want to use this version, type

nvm use 6.11.2

C:\Users\john> npm
'npm' is not recognized as an internal or external command,
operable program or batch file.
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to open a new command prompt to pick up the new environment variables.

Comment: For people who use `nvm 1.1.5`, just upgrade to `nvm 1.1.7` then it works.

Answer (score 1):

For nvm version 1.1.7

> ```
> Usage:
>   nvm on                       : Enable node.js version management.
>   nvm off                      : Disable node.js version management.
> ```

Try `nvm on` .